# How to custom style angular-bootstrap-toggle?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am including angular-bootstrap-toggle in my library for toggling. I am also setting the on and off values. But the labels are overflowing, and is overlapped by the toggle button - [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuIsp.png), and [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOdnZ.png). I want to set my own style. According to the documentation online on angular-bootstrap-toggle, we can just add style attribute. I tried that, but am getting an error saying ': expected' as shown here:

```
 <div>
     <toggle ng-model="selectedTicket" ng-change="toggleTicket()" on="Ticket" off="Image" style="ami"></toggle>
 </div>
```

Style is defined in my index.html file under  after including all the css files as:

```
<style>
        .toggle.ami {
            width: 80px;
        }
        .toggle.ami .toggle-handle{
            width: 80px;
        }
</style>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to help me overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you change "style" to "class" in your HTML:

```
<div>
  <toggle ng-model="selectedTicket" ng-change="toggleTicket()" on="Ticket" off="Image" class="ami"></toggle>
</div>
```

You will also need to remove the `.` from your `.toggle` CSS selector because toggle isn't a class:

```
<style>
  toggle.ami {
    width: 80px;
  }
  toggle.ami .toggle-handle{
    width: 80px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Do you mean that I add my styles to a .styl file without putting them in style tags, and add that class to my toggle?

Comment: No, you should be able to add them to your index.html file inside <style> tags like you did in the question above.  I just noticed you'll need to remove the `.` from your selectors (see edit above).